# Object references in JavaScript ecma6

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, get

How to store objects of a class in an array and use the objects get function?

```
//in storage class
export class DataStorage{
    constructor(type, value){
        this._type = type;
        this._value = value;
    }
    get type() {
        return this._type;
    }

//store objects of type storage class
import {DataStorage} from "./DataStorage.js";
export var aDS = [];
export function addDataStorage(type, value){
    aDS.push(new DataStorage(type, value));
} 

//use get function in storage class
import * as DS from "./AllDataStorage.js";
export function calculate(){
    for(var i = 0; i < DS.aDS.length; i++){
        console.log(DS.aDS[i].getType()); //Does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6.

Answer (score 1):

You have a getter function, you don't need `.getType()` you need `.type`.